# Enum is not populating with the right options in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, enums

I am new to ASP.NET and I am facing a problem that when I populate the enum as a list, it sets a default value and doesn't show the first option from the `<option>` tag as the start it shows it like one of the options only.

In `.cshtml` file

```
<label asp-for="Type" class="control-label">enum list</label>
<select class="form-select"asp-for="Type" asp items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Type>()" oninput="this.className = 'form-select'">
    <option value="">select pls</option>
</select>
<span asp-validation-for="Type" class="text-danger"></span>
```

it shows as

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pKqu.png)

What I wanted it to show is the option tag  like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux8tl.png)

This the enum:

```
public enum Type
{
    [Display(Name = "New")]
    New,
    [Display(Name = "Reorder")]
    Reorder
}
```

And I am using it in a model class like this:

```
public class Model1
{
    // other fields
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(24)")]
    [Required]
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    //others
}
```

View model class:

```
public class VM
{
    // others
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public Model1 Model1{ get; set; }
    // others
}
```

In `MyController` action method, I assigned the values of the `Model1` to the view model used in the view:

```
    // GET: type/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        VM modelVM = new VM()
            {
                Model1= new Model1()
            };

        return View(modelVM);
    }
```

I tried making it with a `SelectListItem` but it still had the same problem.

I use multiple languages so the `[Display(Name = "")]` is important for translation it won't work with `SelectListItem`.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the view model property nullable:

```
public class VM
{
    public Type? Type { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise, the property of the non-nullable enum type will be initialized with the default value for your enum, which is the first enum member, `Type.New`. And because the `Type` property then has a value, it will be used to select the default value for the `<select>`.

But if the property is nullable, then the value of the property is `null` so the `<select>` will not default to a value from the enum and instead show the first option with `value=""` instead.